# Load Buffered Image in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

My Game Class:

```
public class Game implements Runnable{

    .....
private BufferedImage test;

    private void initial(){
        test=ImageLoader.loadImage("/img/back.jpg");
    }
    ......
}
```

My ImageLoader Class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is a img folder under res folder.

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at ImageLoader.loadImage(ImageLoader.java:10)
    at Game.initial(Game.java:25)
    at Game.run(Game.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think it cant read the image but i didnt find alternative way.I want to read `BufferedImage`.

SOLUTION: Create a package and add the image in this package. And use package name.

Comment: The image is in folder.I checked it

Comment: Well, `getResource()` **can** return `null` "if no resource with this name is found". See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

Comment: Please, add your solution as an answer and accept it :)